# Determine if focusedProperty change is permanent in JavaFX

Tags: java, focus, javafx-2

In [**Java's** AWT FocusEvent class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/FocusEvent.html):

> There are two levels of focus events: permanent and temporary.
>
> **Permanent** focus change events occur when focus is directly moved from one Component to another, such as through a call to requestFocus() or as the user uses the TAB key to traverse Components.
>
> **Temporary** focus change events occur when focus is temporarily lost for a Component as the indirect result of another operation, such as Window deactivation or a Scrollbar drag. In this case, the original focus state will automatically be restored once that operation is finished, or, for the case of Window deactivation, when the Window is reactivated.

In **JavaFX**, a [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) can be added to the [focusedProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.FocusedProperty.html) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549296/how-perform-task-on-javafx-textfield-at-onfocus-and-outfocus), but how does one determine if the change is permanent?