# Focus Listener for JavaFX Nodes

Tags: java, javafx

I am a beginner in JavaFX. I am really stuck at this point. :( And sorry if my English is poor.

I have two stack panes in my JavaFX program. I want to add a focus listener to both of these stack panes.

It should be such that, when I click on one stack pane, it should activate the focus gained method for this stack pane.

Once I click on another stack pane, the 1st stack pane should give a call to its focus lost method, and the current stack pane's focus gained method should be called. Just like we have focus events in the Swing Package.

Currently I have tried this:

```
stackPane.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                    if (newValue.booleanValue()) {
                        focusGained(stackPane);
                    } else {
                        focusLost(stackPane);
                    }
                }
            });

private void focusGained(StackPane stackPane){
    System.out.println("Focus Gained.");
}

private void focusLost(StackPane stackPane){
    System.out.println("Focus Lost.");
}
```

I have also tried to set the focus traversable property on the stack pane i.e.

```
stackPane.setFocusTraversable(true);
```

These are not working properly. When I run it, the output only shows these 3 lines, no matter how many times I click on the stack panes.

```
Focus Gained.
Focus Lost.
Focus Gained.
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't get the same results as you. Do you have an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How perform task on javaFX TextField at onfocus and outfocus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549296/how-perform-task-on-javafx-textfield-at-onfocus-and-outfocus)

Answer (score 7):

Well, it's a bit late but it might help others.
This works fine:

```
root.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
    focusState(newValue);
});

private void focusState(boolean value) {
    System.out.println(value ? "Focus gained" : "Focus lost");
}
```

Comment: @Tunaki ...just out of curiosity, you edited my answer but I see no change in what I answered. What exactly did you edit?

Comment: I fixed the indent level of the answer: you just need 4 spaces to format as code.