# Enabling a disabled button when TableView row selected

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a button on my interface that is disabled by default. I want it to become enabled when the user selects a row in my TableView and becomes disabled again when the user clicks elsewhere. What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 11):

Seems like a perfect place to use JavaFX [Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html):

```
TableView<String> tableView = new TableView<>(tableData);

TableColumn<String, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>();

Button button = new Button("Button");
button.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.isEmpty(tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));
```

This example disables the `Button` when the user has selected nothing or cleared his selection and becomes enabled as soon as at least one row is being selected.

Comment: It is working fine for me. Remember: This is not a focus listener. You actually have to clear the selection to disable the Button.

Answer (score 0):

add a focus listener to your tableView object, and on focus set 
`button.enable = true;` on lost focus then `button.enable = false;`

the code will look a bit like

```
class myClass implements FocusListener
{
    TableView.addFocusListener(this);

    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
        button.enable=true;
    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
        button.enable=false;
    }


}
```

[Focus listener toturial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html)

Comment: I tried this but it won't accept .addFocusListener saying the classic "cannot find symbol". Might be worth mentioning that the tableview is not of a generic type.

Comment: Doing a bit of research I saw that javafx doesn't have a addFocusListener method. Does this have anything to do with it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549296/how-perform-task-on-javafx-textfield-at-onfocus-and-outfocus , also check the Javafx binding from the second answer