# How to make TextFormatter work only if field is in focus?

Tags: java, validation, javafx-8, text-formatting

I have a `TextFormatter`:

```
mailTextField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
    int maxLength = 100;

    if (change.isAdded()) {
        if(change.getControlNewText().length()>maxLength){
            if(change.getText().length()==1){
                change = null;
                System.out.println("Reached max!");
            }else{
                int allowedLength = maxLength - change.getControlText().length();
                change.setText(change.getText().substring(0, allowedLength));
                System.out.println("Cut paste!");
            }
        }

        if(change!=null){
            System.out.println("Mail check: "+change.getControlNewText());
            if(Validation.mail(change.getControlNewText())){
                showCorrectIcon(mailTextField);
                }else{
                showErrorIcon(mailTextField);
            }
        }
    }
    return change;
}));
```

Since initial mail is stored in database, I don't want to show correct icon for it, but only if user tries to adjust it. Is it possible to make `TextFormatter` work only in case mail field is in focus?

Comment: Maybe you change the TextFormatter on Focus changed. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549296/how-perform-task-on-javafx-textfield-at-onfocus-and-outfocus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `isFocused()` function: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#isFocused--

At the start of your TextFormatter you could do:

```
if (!mailTextField.isFocused()) {
    return change;
}
```

Full example:

```
mailTextField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(change -> {
    if (!mailTextField.isFocused()) {
        return change;
    }

    int maxLength = 100;

    if (change.isAdded()) {
        if(change.getControlNewText().length()>maxLength){
            if(change.getText().length()==1){
                change = null;
                System.out.println("Reached max!");
            }else{
                int allowedLength = maxLength - change.getControlText().length();
                change.setText(change.getText().substring(0, allowedLength));
                System.out.println("Cut paste!");
            }
        }

        if(change!=null){
            System.out.println("Mail check: "+change.getControlNewText());
            if(Validation.mail(change.getControlNewText())){
                showCorrectIcon(mailTextField);
                }else{
                showErrorIcon(mailTextField);
            }
        }
    }
    return change;
}));
```